# How to save result from Google Place Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, stimulusjs

Firstly I would like to let you guys know that I have already checked many stack overflow Q&As, but I couldn't get the right solution.

I made a rails app by following the youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtgwdLiJ5hA&t

It worked well including markerCluster which didn't cover in that youtube.

**However, what I tried to add was that each user has his or her own search result(only the last one), and after hitting search button the page will be redirected to the same page with queries which have information about autocompleted place.**

I succeeded in redirecting the same page with queries, but it was too hard to make the same map object as the one just after autocompleting.

The closest answer was as below, but it didn't work perfectly because AutocompleteService didn't return the first prediction as the place I wanted even though I put the exact address chosen just before redirecting.

[How to set a default value for a Google places API auto complete textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402928/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-a-google-places-api-auto-complete-textbox)

The second trial was just copying some part of autocomplete object (bounds, location) and applying to the map object after redirecting. It seemed to work about only position, but the map display result has something wrong with boundary and the area seen.

The third trial was using place_id with the second trial, but I didn't think it would work.

I really wanted to insert the address text, select the address I chose before redirecting, and create autocomplete 'place_change' event AUTOMATICALLY as soon as the page was redirected. However, I have no idea how to do that.

Here is the main_map_controller.js (it is stimulus js)

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
    // currentUrl is for redirecting to root_path in javascript
    static targets = ["field", "map", "jsonMarkers", "currentUrl", "east", "north", "south", "west", "lat", "lng", "zoom"];

    connect() {
        if (typeof(google) != "undefined") {
            this.initializeMap();
        }
    }

    initializeMap() {
        this._jason_locations = JSON.parse(this.jsonMarkersTarget.value);
        this.map();
        this.markerCluster();
        this.autocomplete();
        this.placeChanged();
        // this.initialAutocomplete();
        this.setPlace();
        console.log('this.eastTarget.value:', this.eastTarget.value)
    }

    hasQuery() {
        if (this.fieldTarget.value != "" && this.eastTarget.value != "" && this.northTarget.value != "" && this.southTarget.value != "" &&
                this.westTarget.value != "" && this.latTarget.value != "" && this.lngTarget.value != "" && this.zoomTarget.value != ""
            )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    // Google map initialization
    map() {
        if (this._map == undefined) {
            if (this.hasQuery())
            {
                this._map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapTarget, {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(this.latTarget.value),
                        parseFloat(this.lngTarget.value)
                    ),
                    zoom: 13
                });

            } else {
                this._map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapTarget, {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(
                        0,
                        0
                    ),
                    zoom: 13
                });
            }
            // Try HTML5 geolocation
            var cur_map = this._map;
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    cur_map.setCenter({
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    })
                });
            }
        }
        return this._map;
    }

    // markerCluster() make a group of markers
    markerCluster() {
        let current_map = this.map();
        if (this._marker_cluster == undefined) {
            var markers = this._jason_locations.map((location, i) => {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: parseFloat(location["latitude"]),
                        lng: parseFloat(location["longitude"])
                    }
                });
                marker.addListener('click', () => {
                    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: `<p>${location.address}</p>`
                    });
                    infoWindow.open(current_map, marker);
                });
                return marker;
            });
            this._marker_cluster = new MarkerClusterer(this.map(),
                markers,
                {imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m'}
            );
        }
        return this._markers_cluster;
    }

    // Autocomplete function. It suggests the full address. 'formatted_address' was added to use user's bad behavior instead of
    // using placeChanged(), but 'formatted_address' saved was not 100% same as the result address of autocomplete, so I didtn' use it.
    // I don't understand why???
    autocomplete() {
        if (this._autocomplete == undefined) {
            this._autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.fieldTarget);
            this._autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map());
            this._autocomplete.setFields(['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name', 'formatted_address', 'place_id']);
            this._autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.placeChanged.bind(this));
        }
        return this._autocomplete;
    }

    // If user typed strange word after autocomplete done, we should not allow to search with that word.
    placeChanged() {
        this._place_changed = this.fieldTarget.value;
    }

    // Because AutoComplete cannot have initial place, I had to use another class, AutocompleteService.
    initialAutocomplete() {
        if (this.fieldTarget.value == undefined || this.fieldTarget.value == "")
            return;
        let autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
        let request = { input: this.fieldTarget.value };
        autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(request, (predictionsArr, placesServiceStatus) => {
            console.log('predictionArr:', predictionsArr);
            console.log('placesServiceStatus:', placesServiceStatus);

            let placeRequest = { placeId: predictionsArr[0].place_id };
            let placeService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map());
            placeService.getDetails(placeRequest, (placeResult, placeServiceStatus) => {
                console.log('placeResult:', placeResult)
                console.log('placeServiceStatus:', placeServiceStatus);
                this.setPlace(placeResult);
            });
        });
    }

    // setPlace(placeResult) {
    setPlace() {
        // let place = this.autocomplete().getPlace();
        // let place = placeResult;

        if (!this.hasQuery()) {
            return;
        }

        console.log('this.eastTarget.value:', this.eastTarget.value)
        console.log('this.northTarget.value:', this.northTarget.value)
        console.log('this.southTarget.value:', this.southTarget.value)
        console.log('this.westTarget.value:', this.westTarget.value)

        // let bound = {
        //     east: parseFloat(this.eastTarget.value),
        //     north: parseFloat(this.northTarget.value),
        //     south: parseFloat(this.southTarget.value),
        //     west: parseFloat(this.westTarget.value)
        // }
        // console.log('bounds:', bound)

        // // this.map().fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        // // this.map().setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        // this.map().fitBounds(bound);

        // let bounds = this.map().getBounds();
        // console.log('bounds:', bounds)
        let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(this.southTarget.value), parseFloat(this.westTarget.value)),
            new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(this.northTarget.value), parseFloat(this.eastTarget.value))
        );
        this.map().fitBounds(bounds);
        this.map().setCenter({
            lat: parseFloat(this.latTarget.value),
            lng: parseFloat(this.lngTarget.value)
        });


        let zoom = this.map().getZoom();
        console.log('zoom:', zoom)

        let center = this.map().getCenter();
        console.log('center:', center)

        document.getElementById("search-area").innerHTML = `Near ${this.fieldTarget.value}`;

        this._jason_locations.forEach( location => {
            var position = {
                lat: parseFloat(location["latitude"]),
                lng: parseFloat(location["longitude"])
            }
            console.log('position:', position)
            if (bounds.contains(position)) {
                document.getElementById(location["id"]).classList.remove("d-none")
            } else {
                document.getElementById(location["id"]).classList.add("d-none")
            }

        });
        // this.latitudeTarget.value = place.geometry.location.lat();
        // this.longitudeTarget.value = place.geometry.location.lng();
    }

    reloadMap() {
        let place = this.autocomplete().getPlace();


        console.log(place)

        // this.setPlace(place);

        if (place == undefined || this.fieldTarget.value == "" || this._place_changed != this.fieldTarget.value || !place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Address is invalid!");
            return;
        }

        this.map().fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        this.map().setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        console.log('place.geometry.viewport:', place.geometry.viewport)
        console.log('place.geometry.location:', place.geometry.location)


        let bounds = this.map().getBounds();
        console.log('bounds:', bounds)

        let zoom = this.map().getZoom();
        console.log('zoom:', zoom)

        console.log('place.place_id:', place.place_id)

        // This code was redirect root_path with query, but there was a problem that map was reloaded twice, so removed it.
        // If adding query is not a solution for having each user's recent search history, then what else would it be?
        let jsonParams = { "address": this.fieldTarget.value, ...bounds.toJSON(), ...place.geometry.location.toJSON(), "zoom": zoom.toString() };
        const params = new URLSearchParams(jsonParams);
        console.log(params.toString());

        // Redirect to /posts/?address=xxxxx
        console.log('params:', `${this.currentUrlTarget.value}/?${params.toString()}`);
        window.location.href = `${this.currentUrlTarget.value}/?${params.toString()}`;
        console.log('window.location.href:', window.location.href)
    }

    // prohibit Enter key, only allow to hit the search button.
    preventSubmit(e) {
        if (e.key == "Enter") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yay, I finally figured it out by getting a hint from the following stack overflow site.

[Google Maps map.getBounds() immediately after a call to map.fitBounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506035/google-maps-map-getbounds-immediately-after-a-call-to-map-fitbounds)

What I fixed was modifying the second trial.
I didn't pass over the result of fitBounds() of autocomplete but viewport bounds of autocomplete itself, and after redirecting I wrapped the all codes after fitBounds() into the 'bound_changed' event handler with the help of the above solution.

Here is my fixed code, and it worked well. (Sorry about unused code and comment. I want to leave it for the record)

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
    // currentUrl is for redirecting to root_path in javascript
    static targets = ["field", "map", "jsonMarkers", "currentUrl", "east", "north", "south", "west", "lat", "lng"];

    connect() {
        if (typeof(google) != "undefined") {
            this.initializeMap();
        }
    }

    initializeMap() {
        this._jason_locations = JSON.parse(this.jsonMarkersTarget.value);
        this.map();
        this.markerCluster();
        this.autocomplete();
        this.placeChanged();
        // this.initialAutocomplete();
        this.setPlace();
        console.log('this.eastTarget.value:', this.eastTarget.value)
    }

    hasQuery() {
        if (this.fieldTarget.value != "" && this.eastTarget.value != "" && this.northTarget.value != "" && this.southTarget.value != "" &&
                this.westTarget.value != "" && this.latTarget.value != "" && this.lngTarget.value != ""
            )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    // Google map initialization
    map() {
        if (this._map == undefined) {
            if (this.hasQuery())
            {
                this._map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapTarget, {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(this.latTarget.value),
                        parseFloat(this.lngTarget.value)
                    )
                    // zoom: parseInt(this.zoomTarget.value)
                });

            } else {
                this._map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapTarget, {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(
                        0,
                        0
                    ),
                    zoom: 13
                });
            }
            // Try HTML5 geolocation
            var cur_map = this._map;
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    cur_map.setCenter({
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    })
                });
            }
        }
        return this._map;
    }

    // markerCluster() make a group of markers
    markerCluster() {
        let current_map = this.map();
        if (this._marker_cluster == undefined) {
            var markers = this._jason_locations.map((location, i) => {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: parseFloat(location["latitude"]),
                        lng: parseFloat(location["longitude"])
                    }
                });
                marker.addListener('click', () => {
                    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: `<p>${location.address}</p>`
                    });
                    infoWindow.open(current_map, marker);
                });
                return marker;
            });
            this._marker_cluster = new MarkerClusterer(this.map(),
                markers,
                {imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m'}
            );
        }
        return this._markers_cluster;
    }

    // Autocomplete function. It suggests the full address. 'formatted_address' was added to use user's bad behavior instead of
    // using placeChanged(), but 'formatted_address' saved was not 100% same as the result address of autocomplete, so I didtn' use it.
    // I don't understand why???
    autocomplete() {
        if (this._autocomplete == undefined) {
            this._autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.fieldTarget);
            this._autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map());
            this._autocomplete.setFields(['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);
            this._autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.placeChanged.bind(this));
        }
        return this._autocomplete;
    }

    // If user typed strange word after autocomplete done, we should not allow to search with that word.
    placeChanged() {
        this._place_changed = this.fieldTarget.value;
    }

    // Because AutoComplete cannot have initial place, I had to use another class, AutocompleteService.
    initialAutocomplete() {
        if (this.fieldTarget.value == undefined || this.fieldTarget.value == "")
            return;
        let autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
        let request = { input: this.fieldTarget.value };
        autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(request, (predictionsArr, placesServiceStatus) => {
            console.log('predictionArr:', predictionsArr);
            console.log('placesServiceStatus:', placesServiceStatus);

            let placeRequest = { placeId: predictionsArr[0].place_id };
            let placeService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map());
            placeService.getDetails(placeRequest, (placeResult, placeServiceStatus) => {
                console.log('placeResult:', placeResult)
                console.log('placeServiceStatus:', placeServiceStatus);
                this.setPlace(placeResult);
            });
        });
    }

    // setPlace(placeResult) {
    setPlace() {
        // let place = this.autocomplete().getPlace();
        // let place = placeResult;

        if (!this.hasQuery()) {
            return;
        }

        console.log('this.eastTarget.value:', this.eastTarget.value)
        console.log('this.northTarget.value:', this.northTarget.value)
        console.log('this.southTarget.value:', this.southTarget.value)
        console.log('this.westTarget.value:', this.westTarget.value)

        // let bound = {
        //     east: parseFloat(this.eastTarget.value),
        //     north: parseFloat(this.northTarget.value),
        //     south: parseFloat(this.southTarget.value),
        //     west: parseFloat(this.westTarget.value)
        // }
        // console.log('bounds:', bound)

        // // this.map().fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        // // this.map().setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        // this.map().fitBounds(bound);

        // let bounds = this.map().getBounds();
        // console.log('bounds:', bounds)
        let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(this.southTarget.value), parseFloat(this.westTarget.value)),
            new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(this.northTarget.value), parseFloat(this.eastTarget.value))
        );
        this.map().fitBounds(bounds);

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map(), 'bounds_changed', () => {
            this.map().setCenter({
                lat: parseFloat(this.latTarget.value),
                lng: parseFloat(this.lngTarget.value)
            });

            bounds = this.map().getBounds();
            console.log('bounds:', bounds)

            let zoom = this.map().getZoom();
            console.log('zoom:', zoom)

            let center = this.map().getCenter();
            console.log('center:', center)

            document.getElementById("search-area").innerHTML = `Near ${this.fieldTarget.value}`;

            this._jason_locations.forEach( location => {
                var position = {
                    lat: parseFloat(location["latitude"]),
                    lng: parseFloat(location["longitude"])
                }
                console.log('position:', position)
                if (bounds.contains(position)) {
                    document.getElementById(location["id"]).classList.remove("d-none")
                } else {
                    document.getElementById(location["id"]).classList.add("d-none")
                }

            });
            // this.latitudeTarget.value = place.geometry.location.lat();
            // this.longitudeTarget.value = place.geometry.location.lng();
        })
    }

    reloadMap() {
        let place = this.autocomplete().getPlace();
        console.log(place)

        // this.setPlace(place);

        if (place == undefined || this.fieldTarget.value == "" || this._place_changed != this.fieldTarget.value || !place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Address is invalid!");
            return;
        }

        // This code was redirect root_path with query, but there was a problem that map was reloaded twice, so removed it.
        // If adding query is not a solution for having each user's recent search history, then what else would it be?
        // let jsonParams = { "address": this.fieldTarget.value, ...bounds.toJSON(), ...place.geometry.location.toJSON(), "zoom": zoom.toString() };
        let jsonParams = { "address": this.fieldTarget.value, ...place.geometry.viewport.toJSON(), ...place.geometry.location.toJSON()};

        const params = new URLSearchParams(jsonParams);

        // Redirect to /posts/?address=xxxxx
        window.location.href = `${this.currentUrlTarget.value}/?${params.toString()}`;
    }

    // prohibit Enter key, only allow to hit the search button.
    preventSubmit(e) {
        if (e.key == "Enter") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```